# Как исправить A constant value is expected в Switch case?

Tags: c#

Есть класс EventType:

```
public class EventType
{
    public const int UnhandledException = 601;

    private int currentEventId;
    public EventType(int eventId)
    {
        currentEventId = eventId;
    }

    public static implicit operator EventType(int eventId)
    {
        return new EventType(eventId);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EventType eventType, int eventId)
    {
        return eventType.currentEventId == eventId;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EventType eventType, int eventId)
    {
        return eventType.currentEventId != eventId;
    }
}
```

В одном месте я использую Switch Case:

```
EventType eventType = new EventType(102);
switch (eventType)
{
    case EventType.UnhandledException:
        break;
}
```

Здесь компилятор задаёт ошибку A constant value is expected как это исправить? Сразу хочу сказать, что нельзя преобразовать класс в enum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мои извинение, я чуть поторопился с вопросом, решил его добавив метод:

```
public static implicit operator int(EventType eventType)
    {
        return eventType.currentEventId;
    }
```